# Javascript firefox can't find values all other browsers do

Tags: javascript, firefox, cross-browser, scope

```
function ganttChart(gContainerID) {

    this.gContainer = document.getElementById(gContainerID);    // The container the chart          this.gCurrentDragBar = -1;
    this.gIsDraggingBar = false;
    this.gMouseStartX = 0;
    this.gMouseStartY = 0;
    this.gBarStartX = 0;
    this.gBarStartY = 0;
    this.gBarBeingDragged;
    this.gCurrentMouseX;
    this.gCurrentMouseY;

    // On mouse move
    this.gAttatchMove = function(self) {

        self.gContainer.onmousemove = function(evt) {
            if (self.gIsDraggingBar) {

                self.gUpdateMousePos(evt);
                self.gBarBeingDragged.style.left = (self.gBarStartX - (self.gMouseStartX - self.gCurrentMouseX)) + "px";

                //%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
                // PRINTS MESSAGE HERE
                document.getElementById("db").innerHTML = "Bar start: " + self.gBarStartX + "<br />Mouse start:" + self.gMouseStartX + "<br />Mouse current:" + self.gCurrentMouseX;
                //%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
            }
        }; 
        self.gContainer.onmouseup = function() {
            self.gIsDraggingBar = false;
        };

    }
    var self = this;
    this.gAttatchMove(self);

    // Update mouse coords
    this.gUpdateMousePos = function(evt) {
        if (window.event) {
            this.gCurrentMouseX = event.x;
            this.gCurrentMouseY = event.y;
        }
        else {
            this.gCurrentMouseX = evt.x;
            this.gCurrentMouseY = evt.y;
        }
    }

    // Sets up the bar mouse events
    gSetupMouseEvents = function(gBar, i, self) {

        gBar.onmouseover = function() {
            gBarHighlight(gBar, self.gData[i][1], self.gData[i][2]);
        };
        gBar.onmouseout = function() {
            gBarUnHighlight(gBar, self.gData[i][1], self.gData[i][2]);
        };
        gBar.onmousedown = function(evt) {

            // Initialise
            self.gCurrentDragBar = i;
            self.gBarBeingDragged = document.getElementById("gBar" + i);
            self.gIsDraggingBar = true;

            // Set initial positions
            self.gUpdateMousePos(evt);
            self.gMouseStartX = self.gCurrentMouseX;
            self.gMouseStartY = self.gCurrentMouseY;
            self.gBarStartX = self.gBarBeingDragged.offsetLeft;
            self.gBatStartY = self.gBarBeingDragged.offsetTop;
        };


    }

}
```

The values printed out are:

**Firefox:**

```
Bar start: 0
Mouse start:undefined
Mouse current:undefined
```

**Chrome**

```
Bar start: 0
Mouse start:163
Mouse current:165
```

**IE**

```
Bar start: 1
Mouse start:3
Mouse current:19
```

I'm not worried about varying values between IE/Chrome I can debug that (just the way mouse position is interpreted) but firefox not picking any values is confusing me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mouse position is given in the "clientX" and "clientY" properties of the event object, not "x" and "y".

Comment: Anyone know why X and Y worked?  It was very buggy but worked in IE and worked 100% fine in chrome.

Comment: Well IE is IE. Chrome (well, WebKit) seems to respect a different subset of IE vagaries than Firefox.

Comment: The more I used Chrome the more impressed I am with it, it runs very well on this PC when IE/FF are slow as

Answer (score 1):

```
    this.gCurrentMouseX = evt.x;
```

You don't want to use `.x`. It doesn't exist on a [standard DOM MouseEvent](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-MouseEvent) object (which is why Firefox doesn't have it) and even in IE, it's usually not what you want. It's relative to the nearest positioned ancestor, where the meaning of ‘positioned’ may vary. It's generally better to get page-relative co-ordinates.

Unfortunately, the `pageX` property that gives you this is also not a standard Event property, so although it is supported by IE9, Firefox, WebKit etc, you can't guarantee it's there. You can instead use `clientX`, which is standard, but is relative to the viewport, so to correct it in case the viewport has scrolled, you have to add the `scrollLeft` of the `documentElement` (unless you're in IE Quirks Mode, in which case it's the `body` instead... don't be in Quirks Mode!).

(The other standard positioning property on MouseEvent is `screenX`, but that's largely useless except for positioning popups. There are also the non-standard properties `offsetX` and `layerX` which are even more useless.)

```
    if (window.event) {
```

Better to test for the standard first (`evt` not being `undefined`), and only fall back to `window.event` for IE<9. Otherwise you may not get what you expect on browsers that support both, or where there's something else (eg a variable or element) defined called `event`.

```
// Update mouse coords
this.gUpdateMousePos = function(evt) {
    if (evt===undefined) evt= window.event;

    if ('pageX' in evt) {
        this.gCurrentMouseX = evt.pageX;
        this.gCurrentMouseY = evt.pageY;
    } else {
        this.gCurrentMouseX = evt.clientX+document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
        this.gCurrentMouseY = evt.clientY+document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    }
}
```

This gives you page-relative co-ordinates. If you want to calculate position relative to a particular element you then have to subtract the page-relative co-ordinates of that element, typically using an `offsetLeft`/`offsetParent` loop. Though there are lots more potential browser problems there too. Sigh. Frameworks can help here. Although to be honest most of them still trip up on some of the uglier corner cases.

(It would be jolly nice if some helpful organisation would specify MouseEvent `pageX`/`pageY` as being standard, and add element/view `pageLeft`/`pageTop` properties to match... I can dream...)

Comment: +1, thank you.  I have experimented with the viewport as you pointed out in Chrome, IE 8 and FF, but it makes no difference to the clientX/clientY properties when the window is scrolled, resized etc, so don't find a case where scrollLeft/top are necessary?

Comment: That's the problem, it doesn't make a difference to `clientY` when you scroll down: scroll to the bottom of the page and click in the top of the viewport and you'll still get `clientY==0`. If you are positioning something relative to the viewport (eg an element with `position: fixed`), that's fine, but it's more common to want page-relative co-ordinates, in which case the fixup is necessary. Of course if your main page doesn't scroll (eg because you've got a child element with `overflow: scroll` instead of scrolling the page itself), that's when it won't make a difference.